# Compare Between GitHub Repo Code To PyPi Package

Tags: python, pypi

I upload my repository to PyPi every now and then.
I want to check difference between my code in GitHub repository to the package that was uploaded to PyPi. I have searched internet for such examples but have not been able to find any and feel a bit clueless on how to execute that.

Comment: Look up the Unix utility `patch`. It essentially runs `diff` over every file in a particular location.

Comment: @MattDMo `patch` doesn't run `diff`.

Comment: "*…have not been able to find any*" [examples]. Because nobody does this. Why do you need it? You don't remember from what commit you have created a version of your package? Use tags for that.

Comment: @phd I know, I could have chosen my wording differently. *"It can be functionally equivalent to running `diff`..."* might have worked better.

Comment: Well, there is no way other than to download a package from a release, extract the package and compare.